# Extended email signature

Tags: email, email-template

Is it possible to make email signature using HTML? Because I need few image-hyperlinks, text color and preformatted text. Simple email signature doesn't support HTML. Same situation with letterheads and email footers. I created email template as email signature and everything is ok, except that when I insert email-template into my email I can't edit it. It means that the only thing I can send by  email is that template. Are there any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: It is possible to make Email Signature using HTML where you can add images,hyperlink etc.

Can you please share the HTML Email Template that you have designed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I find solution for my issue. Firstly, I created link in letterhead, then select it and choose image icon on toolbar and insert image. All these I did it without HTML, only using standard letterhead toolbar.